# What is the base address of an HttpClient instance supposed to be?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotnet-httpclient

I'm setting up an HttpClient instance to access an api, and I'm trying to populate the HttpClient.BaseAddress field. However, I am confused as to what that BaseAddress should link to. Is it my local port, as with "http://localhost:12345/", or should it be the endpoint url of the api, as with "https://somewhere.com/api/"?

This is for an MVC web application accessing only one api and thus only one server - HttpClient.BaseAddress will not need to be set again.

Comment: It's the common part of the URL that you'll be making requests to.

Comment: You don't have to set that field you know...

Comment: it's the base of where you want to send all the requests to. So yeah setting it to the address of where you're running it from makes no sense - a HTTP request only needs to know where it's going to, not where it's coming from. It's an optional convenience field - you can set it as `https://www.example.com/api.` for instance and then in each individual request specify the rest of the exact URL of the specific request e.g. `employees/324` or something. Or you can leave it blank and just specify a full URL in each request individually.

Answer (score 1):

When TCP/IP client initiates connection to server client should specify address of server process: IP and port. Say port 443 for HTTPS. Operational system of client will allocate port of source automatically from ephimeral ports pool.